# Multiple column values in y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot below data as lines using ggplot. The table looks like this:

```
number total_leaf_cells standard_cells moveable_cells 
    1   exp1            64886          63591          63591      
    2   exp2            64856          63561          63561       
    3   exp3            64919          63624          63624      
    4   exp4            64862          63567          63567       
    5   exp5            64936          63641          63641
```

my code is:

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data = my_data, aes(x = number, y = total_leaf_cells), color = "red") +
      geom_point(data = my_data, aes(x = number, y = moveable_cells), color = "blue")
```

I'm getting following error:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

How do I plot total_leaf_cells, standard_cells, moveable_cells as y-axis values and numbers as x-axis?

Comment: I think you need to `gather` i.e. `gather(df1, key, value, -number) %>% ggplot(., aes(x=number, y = value, color= key)) + geom_point()`

Comment: example with `melt` here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47094031/1100107